# Most efficient way to determine if a row EXISTS and INSERT into MySQL using java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, jdbc

I'm looking at trying to query a table in a MySQL database (I have the primary key, which is comprised of two categories, a name and a number but string comparison), such that this table could have anywhere from very few rows to upwards of hundreds of millions. Now, for efficiency, I'm not exactly sure how costly it is to actually do an `INSERT` query but I have a few options as to go about it:

1. I could query the database to see if the element `EXISTS` and then call an `INSERT` query if it doesn't.
2. I could try to brute force `INSERT` into the database and if it succeeds or fails, so be it.
3. I could initially on program execution, create a cache/store, grab the primary key columns and store them in a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` and then search the key for if the name exists, then if it does, does the key and value combination in the `List<Integer>` exists, if it doesn't, then `INSERT` query the database.
4. ?

Option one really isn't on the table for what I would really implement, just on the list of possible choices. Option two would most likely average better for unique occurrences such that it isn't in the table already. Option three would favour if common occurrences are the case such that a lot are in the cache.

Bearing in mind that option chosen will be iterated over potentially millions of times. Memory usage aside (From option 3), from my calculations it's nothing significant in respect to the capacity available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the database do the work.

You should do the second method.  If you don't want to get a failure, you can use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into t(pk1, pk2, . . . )
    values ( . . . )
    on duplicate key update set pk1 = values(pk1);
```

The only purpose of `on duplicate key update` is to do nothing useful but not return an error.

Why is this the best solution?  In a database, a primary key (or columns declared unique) have an index structure.  This is efficient for the database to use.

Second, this requires only one round-trip to the database.

Third, there are no race conditions, if you have multiple threads or applications that might be attempting to insert the same record(s).

Fourth, the method with `on duplicate key update` will work for inserting multiple rows at once.  (Without `on duplicate key insert`, then a multi-value statement would fail if a single row is duplicated.) Combining multiple inserts into a single statement can be another big efficiency.

Your second option is really the right way to go.

Comment: The main points of your answer are really helpful and you did answer what I was after. Equally though through looking more into `on duplicate key update` I see `INSERT IGNORE` is actually more what I'm after. Since if the primary key conflicts, then I don't want that row to be inserted at all. 

However, there is that nicety of multiple row insertion, which I will need to investigate further.

Comment: @Miniman . . . You should not use `INSERT IGNORE`.  It ignores other errors that you might want to catch (say, if a trigger issues an error or if you have a type error).  The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does *exactly* what you want.  If no values change in the record, no update occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fetching all your result in the third option , you could try using Limit 1 , given the fact that the combination of your name and number form a primary key thus , using limit 1 to fetch the result and then if the result is empty then you can probably insert your desired data. It would lot faster that way.

Comment: I would load all the results into memory for a cache, each result within is unique, such that LIMIT 1 with me having primary key combination is unnecessary. When I meant all the results, I mean trimmed as much as possible, only getting the row data I need and all the relevant data, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a neat way to perform an special insertion. The `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a MySQL extension to the `INSERT` statement. If you specify the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option in the `INSERT` statement and the new row causes a duplicate value in the `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` index, MySQL performs an update to the old row based on the new values:

```
INSERT INTO table(column_list)
VALUES(value_list)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_1 = new_value_1, column_2 = new_value_2;
```